# How to compare variables based on custom priority in python?

Tags: python-3.x

I have a few strings, e.g. `'A', 'B', 'C', 'D'`.

1. I need to set the level of these strings, as in

> `'B' > 'A' > 'D' > 'C'`

2. Two variables will have their values as either of these. So, when I compare those two variables, I should get boolean True or False, like we get when we compare two variables having numeric values. E.g. assume `var1 = 'D' and var2 = 'B'`. So, if we compare:

```
if var1 > var2:
    some code
else:
    other code
```

then it should go to else as 'B' > 'D'.

Hope, I have explained it as I want to. Please suggest.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't use a comparison operator directly without creating your own custom class. However, you could make a dictionary with the value of the character. For example:

```py
values = {"B":4, "A":3, "D":2, "C":1}

if values[var1] > values[var2]:
    some code
else:
    other code
```

Comment: Be aware, that this will raise a `KeyError` if you try to get the value of something not in the `values` dictionary. I suggest you use a try-except block.

Comment: Thanks. The variables will have the specified keys. So, won't need try-except. But will keep that in mind.

Answer (score 0):

Your best bet here is likely to define a dictionary or of each values precedence, and write a method to compare the values:

```py
def compare(left, right):
    values = { "B": 3, "A": 2, "D", 1, "C", 0 }
    
    return values[left] > values[right]

var1 = "B"
var2 = "D"

if compare(var1, var2):
    pass
else
    pass
```

You will not be able to use the `>` operator as operator overloading is not allowed on existing types in python. Were you to create a custom class you would be able to move the `compare` logic into the class' `__gt__`, `__lt__`, `__eq__`, etc methods.

Comment: Thanks, will try this.